# MLFLow artifact logging and retrieve on remote server

Tags: python, mlflow

I am trying to setup a MLFlow tracking server on a remote machine as a systemd service.
I have a sftp server running and created a SSH key pair.

Everything seems to work fine except the artifact logging. MLFlow seems to not have permissions to list the artifacts saved in the `mlruns` directory.

I create an experiment and log artifacts in this way:

```
uri = 'http://192.XXX:8000' 
mlflow.set_tracking_uri(uri)

mlflow.create_experiment('test', artifact_location='sftp://192.XXX:_path_to_mlruns_folder_')

experiment=mlflow.get_experiment_by_name('test')
with mlflow.start_run(experiment_id=experiment.experiment_id, run_name=run_name) as run:
       mlflow.log_param(_parameter_name_, _parameter_value_)     
       mlflow.log_artifact(_an_artifact_, _artifact_folder_name_)
```

I can see the metrics in the UI and the artifacts in the correct destination folder on the remote machine. However, in the UI I receive this message when trying to see the artifacts:

> Unable to list artifacts stored
> under sftp://192.XXX:*path_to_mlruns_folder*/*run_id*/artifacts
> for the current run. Please contact your tracking server administrator
> to notify them of this error, which can happen when the tracking
> server lacks permission to list artifacts under the current run's root
> artifact directory.

I cannot figure out why as the `mlruns` folder has `drwxrwxrwx` permissions and all the subfolders have `drwxrwxr-x`. What am I missing?

---

UPDATE
Looking at it with fresh eyes, it seems weird that it tries to list files through `sftp://192.XXX:`, it should just look in the folder `_path_to_mlruns_folder_/_run_id_/artifacts`. However, I still do not know how to circumvent that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that by default the systemd service is run by root.
Specifying a user and creating a ssh key pair for that user to access the same remote machine worked.

```
[Unit]

Description=MLflow server

After=network.target 

[Service]

Restart=on-failure

RestartSec=20

User=_user_

Group=_group_

ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'PATH=_yourpath_/anaconda3/envs/mlflow_server/bin/:$PATH exec mlflow server --backend-store-uri postgresql://mlflow:mlflow@localhost/mlflow --default-artifact-root sftp://_user_@192.168.1.245:_yourotherpath_/MLFLOW_SERVER/mlruns -h 0.0.0.0 -p 8000' 

[Install]

WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`_user_` and `_group_` should be the same listed by `ls -la` in the `mlruns` directory.